# Запись формулы в таблицу

Tags: c++, математика, visual-c++, формулы

[image: вот в чем проблема]

В общем никак не могу преобразовать эти формулы в visual
Пытался сделать - но не получается. Вот наброски

```
if (x<=0){y=(x+1)/pow(abs(x)+2,3);} 
    else
    if ((x>0)&&(x<=a)){y=pow(exp,x)+cos(x+2);} 
        else 
            if (x>a){y=3*ln(pow(pow(sin,2)x+2,1/5; };}
```

Comment: И что у вас в кода за `a`? Мы должны догадываться о том, какое задание у вас **на самом деле**?

Comment: Там задание очень обширное. А я никак не могу справится именно с преобразованием данных математических формул в код.

Comment: Попытка записать sin²x как `pow(sin,2)x` - это сильно

Answer (score 1):

Ну, раз вы хоть что-то пытались сделать, вот запись ваших функций:

Первая

```
у = (abs(x)+2); 
y = (x+1)/(y*y*y);
```

Вторая

```
y = exp(x)+cos(x+2);
```

Третья

```
y = sin(x);
y = 0.6*log(y*y+2);
```

Естественно, подразумевается, что и `x`, и `y` - типа `double`.